# How do I set a min & max length for a password on HTML

Tags: html, passwords, max, min

This is probably a really simple fix so hoping someone can help!

I have been tasked with setting password parameters where people are asked to have there password between 5-10 characters.

I am able to bring up the error message so that it asks for more characters than 5 but not the one that asks for it to be between 5-10.

I can set the maximum characters to 10 but that just put a block on how many characters you can have in the field rather than ask people for the specific rules that I am looking for.

Any help will be massively appreciated!

This code will set the min length

This one I was sure would work but restricted what I could put in the box instead of setting certain rules

Thanky you so much in advance!!!

Comment: You could use a javascript function with regex.

Comment: I appreciate the help bro but I'm still in the very early staged of HTML right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `minlength` option inside the input like so:

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="password"
       minlength="8" required>
```

Same with maxlength:

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="password"
   maxlength="8" required>
```

Comment: No problem, enjoy! :)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5 we can use :

```
<input type="password" pattern=".{5,10}" required>
```

Comment: Perfect this was exactly what I was looking for!